# Java: comboBox, different tables for each option in the comboBox

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

I want for each option in my combo box, something different to appear on my app. window:different buttons, tables, textfields etc.

I figured the best way is to make a "switch" but I don't really know what to put in the testing area of the switch.

```
package tema3;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Interface {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        new Interface();
    }

    public Interface() {

        JFrame guiFrame = new JFrame();

        guiFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        guiFrame.setTitle("Tema3");
        guiFrame.setSize(1200, 600);

        guiFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null); // seteaza centrat

        String[] tableOptions = { "OPDept", "Order", "OrderItems", "Product",
                "Warehouse", "Customer" };
        // pentru combo box

        final JPanel comboPanel = new JPanel();
        JLabel comboLbl = new JLabel("Tabele:");
        JComboBox tables = new JComboBox(tableOptions);

        comboPanel.add(comboLbl);
        comboPanel.add(tables);

        tables.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {

                comboPanel.setVisible(comboPanel.isVisible());

                switch (???what to insert here???) {

                case "Order": {
                    System.out.println("11111");
                    break;
                }

                case "Product": {
                    System.out.println("2222");
                    break;
                }

                    default: {
                        System.out.print("sd");
                        break;
                    }
                }

            }
        });

        guiFrame.add(comboPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        guiFrame.add(tables, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        guiFrame.setVisible(true);



    }
}
```

Thanks,
Dragos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use method [`getSelectedItem`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html#getSelectedItem%28%29) to get the currently selected item:

```
switch ((String)tables.getSelectedItem()) { ... }
```

Note: You have to cast it to a `String` in order to use it in the switch statement.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are using `Java7` You can write as follows:

```
String s = (String)tables.getSelectedItem();
                switch (s) {
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are not use `Java7 +` , so you cannot **switch** over **string**

so you can convert it to `if(){}.. else{}`

Like that :

```
 String s = (String) tables.getSelectedItem();
 if (s.equals("Order")) {
     System.out.println("11111111");
  } else if (s.equals("Product")) {
      System.out.println("2222222");
  } else {
      System.out.print("sd");
  }
```

[Oracle tutorial :](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html)
          In Java SE 7 and later, you can use a String object in the switch statement's expression.